# Adding a variable number to data

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to take data and add a variable to the number before charting it with d3

However using + in javascript to do the addition simply appends the variable number to the data number instead of adding it?

```
var extraCash = 100
var budget= d3.format(",")(data[1].total_budget+extraCash);
```

The data looks like:

```
{"rows":[["total_budget"],["200"]]},
```

Budget should be 300, but I am getting 200,100

Comment: Are you sure it looks like {"rows":[["total_budget"],["200"]]} and not {"rows":[["total_budget"],["200,"]]} with the comma at the end of 200?

Comment: You need to parse `total_budget` into a number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like `totalCash` is a `String`, try coercion:

```
var budget= d3.format(",")(Number(data[1].total_budget) + extraCash);
```

Other methods:

```
parseFloat(data[1].total_budget) + extraCash

parseInt(data[1].total_budget, 10) + extraCash

+ data[1].total_budget + extraCash /* <-- "unary" operator */
```

These methods all behave differently which can lead to unexpected results. It's a good idea to be familiar with the nuances of each method.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Type_Conversion
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus

Comment: That was the issue. Thank you.